# How to set empty EditText fields to zero from a GridLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I know that there is a setText() method for EditText, but how can you do it when it's in a GridLayout?

When I type this function below for a button click:

```
public void setEmptyToZero()
{
    //Iterate through whole GridLayout to check if there are empty fields 
    //and set them to zero
    String value;
    EditText edt;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows*columns; i++)
    {
        edt = (EditText) gd.getChildAt(i);
        value = edt.getText().toString();
        if(value.equals(""))
        {
            ((EditText) gd.getChildAt(i)).setText(0); //This doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

The app will crash when I test it. I believe that there is something wrong with

```
((EditText) gd.getChildAt(i)).setText(0);
```

But how to do it the correct way?

Comment: You cannot pass integer in setText method, use this setText( 0 +"");.

Comment: I did `((EditText) gd.getChildAt(i)).setText(0 + "");` and `((EditText) gd.getChildAt(i)).setText("0");` but the app will still crash.

Comment: The thing is you should give a default value in the xml of the grid_item and getChildAt() wont return you the editText.